# Couldn't infer type parameter 'TSelected' in Dart null safety migration

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

When I was migrating my dart code to null safety I am getting the following analysis error. I would appreciate if someone can provide a solution and explain the problem in simple terms.

```
1 analysis issue found:
  error • Couldn't infer type parameter 'TSelected'.

Tried to infer 'TSelected' for 'TSelected' which doesn't work:
  Type parameter 'TSelected' is declared to extend 'Comparable<TSelected>' producing 'Comparable<TSelected>'.
The type 'TSelected' was inferred from:
  Parameter 'selector' declared as     'TSelected Function(T)'
                       but argument is 'TSelected Function(T)'.

Consider passing explicit type argument(s) to the generic.
```

Generic extension for sorting:

```
    extension IterableExtensions<T> on Iterable<T> {
        
          Iterable<T> sortBy<TSelected extends Comparable<TSelected>>(TSelected Function(T) selector) =>
             toList()..sort((a, b) => selector(a).compareTo(selector(b)));

          Iterable<T> sortByDescending<TSelected extends Comparable<TSelected>?>(TSelected Function(T) selector) =>
              sortBy(selector).toList().reversed;
    
          T? get firstOrNull {
               return isEmpty ? null : first;
          }
}
```

Usage Example:

```
Model? get lastDateModel => modelList.sortByDescending((val) => value.date).firstOrNull;
```

Model :

```
class Model {
  final Id? id;
  final DateTime? date;

  Model({
    this.id,
    this.date,
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sortBy` method expects a type parameter that extends `Comparable<TSelected>`, but the `sortByDescending` method expects a type parameter that extends `Comparable<TSelected>?`.

See the difference? That last `?` makes is possible to pass a null value instead of a `Comparable<TSelected>`, because you added it into the descending method but not into the original, when you call the original from the descending method, dart doesn't know what to do if you decided to pass null as an argument, so it can't compile.

So the fix is to either add a `?` on the `sortBy` method or remove the `?` from the `sortByDescending` either solution will require some refactoring to make sure the methods still work.